# Crystal Report 11 / Print "Terms and Conditions" on every alternate page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement to print a fixed "Terms and Conditions" (TOC) page on every alternate page.
The objective is so that when the report is printed on a duplex printer (on both sides), the TOC will appear on every sheet of paper.

```
* Page 1 / TOC
* Page 2 / Data
* Page 3 / TOC
* Page 4 / Data
* ... and so on
```

Initial thought was that I could achieve this by putting the TOC in `"Page Header"` and add the suppress logic `"PageNumber mod 2 = 0"`, while the data would be in `"Details"` with suppress logic `"PageNumber mod 2 = 1"`. Therefore, the report will display `"Page Header"` and suppress `"Details"` on odd pages and vice-versa for even pages.

However, there would be a problem when the data does not fit exactly in 1 page.
We would have the following situations:

```
* Page 1 / TOC
* Page 2 / Data A (page 1)
* Page 3 / TOC - "Data A (page 2)" is suppressed
* Page 4 / Data B
```

Or what if the data spans 3 pages?

```
* Page 1 / TOC
* Page 2 / Data A (page 1)
* Page 3 / TOC - "Data A (page 2)" is suppressed
* Page 4 / Data A (page 3)
* Page 5 / TOC - "Data B" is suppressed
```

Any solutions / ideas?

Comment: Try my technique: [Crystal Report: Include Terms and Conditions on a Form Letter](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/23/crystal-report-include-terms-and-conditions-on-a-form-letter/)

Comment: Hi craig, your sample is perfect when handling single page data. But for my report, that is not always the case as the data may flow onto the 2nd page. I modified your report to simulate a 2nd page and everything is messed up as shown in this [image.](http://i61.tinypic.com/11t98js.jpg)

Comment: Offtopic, but much simpler would be to use one-sided printer and paper sheets, having TOC already printed on backside :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use option `New Page After` to force the next section to new page.

In the section where `Toc` is placed... write below formula.

Go to the section expert of the section ---> then tab `Paging` there click on `X-2` of the option `New page After`.

```
if PageNumber mod 2=0
then false               //since Toc comes in first page
else true
```

In section where `Data` comes write below formula.

Go to the section expert of the section ---> then tab `Paging` there click on `X-2` of the option `New page After`.

```
if PageNumber mod 2=0
then true
else false
```

Comment: Hi Siva, since I'm expecting the TOC to appear on every alternate page, it should be placed in the `Page Header` section right? However, the `Page Header` does not have the option for `New Page After`. If I put the TOC into a `Group Header`, then it will appear only at the start of each group of data and not on every alternate page.

Comment: if this is is not possible you can try `new page before` on group header.