# Crystal Reports - printing terms and conditions on the back of every page, including the last one

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, pdf-generation, page-break

There are several questions on here, but none quite answer what I am trying to do.

We have an invoice template in Crystal Reports which we use to generate invoices in both PDF and paper formats. Currently, we print single-sided onto paper which has our Terms and Conditions pre-printed on the reverse. What I need to do is edit the template so that the Terms and Conditions are included on every even-numbered page.

I have seen this answer [Crystal Report 11 / Print "Terms and Conditions" on every alternate page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012392/crystal-report-11-print-terms-and-conditions-on-every-alternate-page) which has a good solution except that this puts the Ts & Cs on every **odd**-numbered page. That means that when we make the PDF version the first page is Terms rather than invoice items. Also, for the paper version, the accounts office staff would have to physically turn over every piece of paper to get them in the right order and facing the correct way (invoice address in the envelope window).

My current design works - sort of. It prints the terms and conditions on the back of every page except the last one, which is no good if it is a 1-page invoice, and also the requirement is for Ts & Cs on the back of every page. There is no grouping.

Here is the layout:

```
Report Header: Suppressed (variable declaration only)

Page Header a: Addresses, suppressed on remainder(pagenumber,2)=0

Page Header b: Column Headings, suppressed on remainder(pagenumber,2)=0

Page Header c: Terms & Conditions, suppressed on remainder(pagenumber,2) <> 0

Details: New Page Before on change of delivery note number

Page Footer: Page numbering, suppressed on remainder(pagenumber,2)=0

Report Footer a: Charges

Report Footer b: Special instructions

Report Footer c: Notes

Report Footer d: VAT Analysis block, New Page After, Print at Bottom of Page
```

How do I get Crystal Reports to print Ts & Cs on the back of the last page? I can't find a way of making Crystal print them because there is no reason for it to have an extra page.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) allows you to add Back-Pages. The process:

a) Exports the report to a pdf file

b) Inserts the standard back-page after each page and saves to a new or to the original pdf export, and

c) Prints and/or emails the resulting pdf file.

Comment: Thanks @MilletSoftware. They may be great pieces of software, but this invoice is generated in our main ERP system via Crystal. The accounts department won't want to run that through a third party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just verified in Crystal, but only in a very simple sample report:

- Insert a second details section below the current one,
- let it have a "page break before",
- and show new section only on last row, and when last page is odd (`(Not OnLastRecord) Or Remainder(PageNumber,2) = 0`).

Comment: Thanks @mweber, but that didn't work in my case. I think it is because there is no need to add a page header where there is no detail to display, and there is no detail to display because there are no more records after the last one. The report footer is the last thing, but I have to convince Crystal to add a last page after that.

Comment: But there is need to add a page header, because the new detail section has a "page break before" it. Unfortunately there's no CR fiddle to show examples :-( Maybe it's possible to share a sample report with saved (dummy) data...